# Hive unable to move query results to a folder

Tags: hive, bigdata, hiveql

I have written a select query in hive to move data to a particular folder.
But I am getting an error. 
Please help.

> Moving data to local directory /Dataproviders/DataSurgery/Order/out/jul24msngtxn/negtxns
>   Failed with exception Unable to move source hdfs://mycluster/tmp/hive/sshuser/253d3089-fcc0-4656-82ca-ccbe893196ed/hive_2018-08-16_06-58-29_220_388527949811395742-1/-mr-10000 to destination /Dataproviders/DataSurgery/Order/out/jul24msngtxn/negtxns
>   FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.MoveTask

```
    INSERT OVERWRITE LOCAL DIRECTORY '/Dataproviders/DataSurgery/Order/out/jul24msngtxn/negtxns/'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\034'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
select * from sourcetable;
```

I have given full permission to the following folders.
But still issue exists

```
hdfs dfs -chmod 777 /tmp/hive
hdfs dfs -chmod -R 777 /Dataproviders/DataSurgery/
```

Comment: Try to insert data to HDFS directory, then use `hdfs dfs -getmerge` to get the data to your local machine

Answer (score 1):

I made a terrible mistake.
The keyword LOCAL should not be present to write into an hdfs directory.
I removed that and query worked fine.
Please find the correct query.

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '/Dataproviders/DataSurgery/Order/out/jul24msngtxn/negtxns/'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\034'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
select * from sourcetable;
```